# margin-top on firefox and chrome

Tags: css, browser, margin

I have a side navigation bar on my website. The sidebar slides with you and changes margin-top.
On google chrome, it follows you, while in firefox, it makes all the boxes follow you which doesn't let you scroll down the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/rDV3T/ This is an example.

```
<span class="hi">HI</span>
<span class="hello">Hello</span>
```

CSS

```
.hi {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-table;
}
.hello {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

If you test on firefox, all the boxes goes down 10 px, while in chrome only the assigned box (hi) goes down.
How could I fix this?
Thank you and sorry for my bad english and explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add `vertical-align: top;` to your `hello` class the example looks the same on all browsers.

```
.hello {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a CSS float property. Instead of `display:inline-table`, use `float:left` to make all the boxes float left. (You will also need a `<div>` with the property `clear:both` after both your spans.)

Comment: When I use float, all my page "breaks". I could fix it but it wouldn't look the same. But thanks anywyas

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem with `display: inline-block` or put in `.hello` `vertical-align: bottom;`

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rDV3T/7/)

```
.hi {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-table;
}
.hello {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

Comment: When I add bottom, nothing changes in both firefox and chrome, but vertical-align: top works. Thank yo anyways

Comment: are you sure? you see here the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rDV3T/9/) with `vertical-align: top;`... however, if you said that the `top` worked for you... ok! :)